# SQL Server query to list all columns in table except the primary key and alternate keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone point me in the direction on how to write a query to pull all the column names from a table that are not primary keys or alternate keys. I would specifically like to exclude alternate keys from my queries.

Comment: You've got SYS.TABLES or INFORMATION_SCHEMA to choose from...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(max) = 'table_name'

SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName

EXCEPT

SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS [tc]
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE [ku] ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ku.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    AND ku.table_name = @tableName
```

Comment: Perfect! Forgot that Except existed!

Comment: for me : AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'

Answer (score 2):

I had to get the list of keys for a simmilar problem but I also had to use COALESCE. The problem was that COALESCE does not work with EXCEPT so I modified Kirill's solution to get rid of it:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
JOIN sysobjects ON TABLE_NAME = name
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tablename
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (
    SELECT name 
    FROM syscolumns 
    WHERE [id] IN (SELECT [id] 
        FROM sysobjects 
        WHERE [name] = @tablename)
        AND colid IN (SELECT SIK.colid 
        FROM sysindexkeys SIK 
        JOIN sysobjects SO ON SIK.[id] = SO.[id]  
        WHERE SIK.indid = 1
            AND SO.[name] = @tablename))
```

Maybe will be help for someone :)

Comment: This answer is useful to get all columns except primary column.

Comment: This worked much better for me, i was using the col_name in a query and this made it quite easy to do what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not a column (or set of columns) is an alternate key cannot be decided by the database system (I use the *alternate key* term as a synonym for a column or set of columns that could have been primary key - they satisfy all PK requirements (unique and NOT NULL) but wasn't chosen to be primary key - for whatever reasons - see [this article for reference](http://www.coders2020.com/what-are-the-different-types-of-keys-in-rdbms)).

There is a lot of "semantic" know-how behind knowing what constitutes a primary key (or an alternate key). While primary keys are "tagged" by being included in the primary key constraint, no such thing exists for alternate keys - since they didn't "make it" to become primary keys, they're just regular columns in your table that *could* be primary key - but aren't.

I don't see how SQL Server would be able to figure those out for you ...